# Removing duplicates from rollup

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I'm trying to create an aggregate row that will sum up the results for the fields. Currently getting extra rows due to the rollup. What I want is to be able to get rid of the extra rows and just have one row at the bottom that sums everything.

```
select  first_name,last_name,count(distinct exam_id) as Exams,count(distinct student_id) as Students, avg(duration) as AvgExamDuration, sum(duration) as TotalDurationWatched
from
(select distinct
    first_name,
    last_name,
    (select exam_id from students where students.id=review_histories.student_id) as exam_id,
    student_id,
    (select sum(videos.duration)/60 from student_files
left join videos on student_files.video_id=videos.id
where student_files.student_id=review_histories.student_id and file_type=10) as duration
from review_histories 
left join users on review_histories.review_user_id=users.id
left join students on review_histories.student_id=students.id
left join exams on students.exam_id=exams.id
where review_histories.review_flag<>false and {{enddate}} 

and ((select value from school_options where exams.school_id=school_options.school_id and option_id=3)=1 or students.course_id in (144006,144007,144008,144009,123203,125690,134470,134462,134494,134524,134526,134533,134539,125691,134537,131250,112231,103966,103968,114418,75846,76874,71942,71948,50051,52282,46844,46843,46831,47899,82710,101793,101115,98383,91051,90798,91187,90689,90696) or (exams.school_id=306 and (select course_name from courses where exams.course_id=courses.id) like 'MAT%'))
) as x
group by first_name,last_name with rollup
```

What I have currently:

| First Name | Last Name | Exams | Students | AVG Duration | Total Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Jones | 1 | 7 | 62.07 | 434.5 |
| Bob |  | 1 | 7 | 62.07 | 434.5 |
| Lee | Doe | 1 | 1 | 4.28 | 4.28 |
| Lee |  | 1 | 1 | 4.28 | 4.28 |
|  |  | 2 | 8 | 54.85 | 438.78 |

What I want:

| First Name | Last Name | Exams | Students | AVG Duration | Total Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Jones | 1 | 7 | 62.07 | 434.5 |
| Lee | Doe | 1 | 1 | 4.28 | 4.28 |
|  |  | 2 | 8 | 54.85 | 438.78 |

Comment: `having grouping(first_name, last_name) in (0, 3)`. [GROUPING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_grouping)

Comment: Alternative to grouping? Don't have access to grouping in my database.